# PHP function for searching for code snippet?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I want to make a Wordpress plugin that counts the number of adsense ads running on a given page.
Is there a PHP function that can find a certain code snippet (google ad code snippet) in a given page after the page has loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Once the page has loaded the code is only accessible by the client browser so PHP (server language) can't access it. You could easily check it with a Javascript function and then send the data via Ajax to your server to save the results or display it on screen or do whatever you want to do with it.

Comment: What is the javascript function for accessing the data on the page and how can i extract the adsense code from it and save it?